# Is there any open iCalender API?

Tags: api, icalendar

Is there any API that I can use and post event data to (for example with querystrings) and get back a file that the visitor can download and add to his calender?

I can of course write the script myself, but if there is a open API I could save some time.

Comment: an specific operating system, programing language ?

Comment: @woliveirajr he is asking for a web service, what does OS or programming language has to do with this?

Answer (score 9):

You could use [iCal4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html)

Answer (score 4):

You asked for a webservice of some sort, and I do not know of one, but if you are using .NET, you can create your own using this library:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/vcalendar.aspx

Comment: For a .NET implementation see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32462475/141172

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's an option for you to generate and send an e-mail to the user containing the appointments you want the to add. By doing this you:

- Haven't jo use any API
- Use the build in auto-parsing feature of Apple Mail (Mac OS & iOS)
- Stay compatible to other users which might not use iCal

Answer (score 2):

I just used [DDay.iCal](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/) which works fine for C#. You can see some documentation [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17980/Adding-iCalendar-Support-to-Your-Program-Part) on how to read/parse from an `.ics` file, and this is what i used to create a new file, checked it works on Outlook and on the iOS email application:

```
public static string GetCalendarAsString(string subject, DateTime start, DateTime end, 
                                         string location, string timeZoneName)
{
    var calendar = new iCalendar();
    var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneName);
    calendar.AddTimeZone(iCalTimeZone.FromSystemTimeZone(timeZone));

    var evt = new Event
              {
                  Start = new iCalDateTime(start),
                  End = new iCalDateTime(end),
                  Location = location,
                  Summary = subject,
                  IsAllDay = false
              };

    calendar.Events.Add(evt);

    var serializer = new iCalendarSerializer();

    return serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
}
```

you can use several other properties, although I only needed these

Answer (score 1):

You can download iCal4J using http://sourceforge.net/projects/ical4j/files/iCal4j/1.0/ical4j-1.0.zip/download