# C# library to generate ICal (ics) files

Tags: c#, icalendar

I am developing an MVC application and need to send appointments info to the client via email (as `*.ics` attachments), I have read many posts about issues that raise when attempting to create this files respecting the standards. So is there a reliable library to do this in `C#` or any other `.Net` language

Note: the smtp is NOT the issue here

**Edit:**

Am looking for a library (dll/nupkg) not a Web API, and specifically for `.Net` or `C#`

Comment: Specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/6714117/141172 for .Net

Comment: i couldn't download it. I found elsewhere this other library DDay.iCal and it got the job done. Can't post the answer here, I will add it as an answer to the question you sent me

Comment: Note that your edit makes this an offtopic question for Stack Overflow ([see #4 here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)), so it's unlikely to be reopened as it stands.

Comment: @Luiso: I would suggest that you create your own answer for the linked question naming the library that you found, along with a brief summary and a link.

Comment: @EricJ.: just did, please check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6595683/is-there-any-open-icalender-api/32462475#32462475)